# C# authorize set role from variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, authorization

While working on a C# ASP.NET MVC 4 website i run into the following problem.

In my code i call the function Authorize like so:

```
private const string GROUP = "Administrators"; //The group that users have to apply to

[Authorize(Roles = GROUP)]
        private string GenerateToken()
        {
            ...
        }
```

But now this website is going to be deployed for multiple locations and the const string GROUP has to be set too other values. In this example you would just change the value Administrators. But i don't want other users to open code files and chance this.

So i have create an xml parser and am parsing this value from a settings xml. But how do i set a constant from an variable. This is not possible because a constant is a constant. But is there a way?

How i parse the xml:

```
public class Settings
{
    public string UserGroup { get; set; }

public Settings(String Loc)
{
    Initialize(Loc);
}

private void Initialize(String Loc)
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(GetXMLAsString(Loc))))
    {
        reader.ReadToFollowing("UserGroup");
        UserGroup = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
    }
}

public string GetXMLAsString(String Loc)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Loc);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
    doc.WriteTo(tx);

    return sw.ToString();
}
```

So is this possible to achieve:

```
private const string GROUP = settings.UserGroup;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question directly, but I solve this problem by having two "levels" of roles:

- The lower level represents protection of a resource, and is fine-grained and application-specific.  In your case, the role might be "CanGenerateToken".   Users are never directly members of these roles.
- The upper level represents groups of users (in an enterprise these are typically business roles).  Here you might have roles such as "MyAppAdministrators".  These roles are members of the fine-grained lower level roles (e.g. "MyAppAdministrators" is a member of "CanGenerateToken").

Unfortunately the standard ASP.NET RoleProvider doesn't support multiple level roles in this way (except when using Windows Groups as roles).  I have implemented a custom RoleProvider that does so, with its own administration UI.

With this approach, your code contains hard-wired authorization based on the lower-level, fine-grained roles that rarely change:

```
[Authorize(Roles="CanGenerateToken")]
public void GenerateToken()
{
    ...
}
```

but an administrator has the flexibility to map higher level "user group" roles to this role.